# Xpath expression (nokogiri) to get tag's child element?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

From my xml, I can get this :

```
<home>
    <creditors>
          <count>2</count>
    </creditors>
</home>
```

OR even this :

```
<home>
    <creditors>
          <moreThan>2</moreThan>
    </creditors>
</home>
```

Which xpath expression can I use to get `"<count>2</count>"` instead of getting only "2" OR to get `"<moreThan>2</moreThan>"` instead of getting "2" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//creditors/count
```

will select all `count` child elements of all `creditors` elements in the XML document.

---

Update per OP's request in comments for a single XPath that selects both `count` and `moreThan` elements:

This XPath,

```
//creditors/*[self::count or self::moreThan]
```

will select all `count` or `moreThan` child elements of all `creditors` elements in the XML document.

Comment: This will return "2" ... but I want to see the tags around to make the difference between <count>2</count> and <moreThan>2</moreThan>. I have only one tag "creditors", but the tag in it can be "count" OR "moreThan". Thanks !

Comment: No, this will select `count` elements.  If you're only seeing `2`, then you're passing the node results through a function that is selecting the string value of the results (or of the first of the results).  Include your actual XPath library call if you still need further help beyond this explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes OP tagged the question, it's `nokogiri`.

Comment: @BartoszPietraszko: You misunderstand.  By requesting the *actual XPath library call*, I'm requesting to see the *actual* line of Nokogiri code; I'm not asking about which XPath library is being used.

Comment: @NoémieHarvey: Well, sure.  Answer updated to show a single XPath that'll select both `count` and `moreThan` child elements of `creditors`.

Comment: @kjhughes You're right, this is the line you talk about : `xml_data = xml_data.map { |node| node.text }.join('-') unless xml_data.is_a?(String)`.  Thanks again !

Comment: @NoémieHarvey: I see no XPath in the code in your comment.

Comment: @kjhughes 
`xml_data = xpath.blank? ? '' : nokogiri_element.xpath(xpath)`
`xml_data = xml_data.map { |node| node.text }.join('-') unless xml_data.is_a?(String)`

Comment: @NoémieHarvey:  If you examine `xml_data` after the first line, before the mapping that takes `.text`, you'll see that the XPath actually returns elements, not strings at that point.  It's the next line of the code that's taking the `.text` of the nodes, leading to your earlier confusion regarding `<count>2</count>` vs `2`.

Comment: @kjhughes I see that, thank you a lot for your time and your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your xpath expression is OK, you just need to convert the element to string:

`doc.xpath("home/creditors/*").to_s
 => "<count>2</count>"`

Please check with queries returning more than one element, to make sure that it's desired behaviour.